# Rails 4.0 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to learn Rails and am making my first app and am running into this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PartsController#show
Couldn't find Part with id=new_ic
```

with the highlighted source:

```
def set_part
@part = Part.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am brand new to rails and i can't figure out what is wrong and I can't find any help online either. The app is a part management system for electronic components. The form gets filled out and the data is saved to the database for future reference/updating. Could someone please help?

Source code time:

**parts/_ic_form.html.erb**

```
    <h1>Add An IC</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @parts do |f| %>


    <%= f.input :component_type, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "IC"} %>
    <%= f.input :ic_model, label: 'IC Model' %>
    <%= f.input :ic_manufacturer, label: 'IC Manufacturer' %>
    <%= f.input :ic_pinCount, label: 'IC Pin-Count' %>
    <%= f.input :ic_mountType, collection: ["Through Hole", "Surface Mount"], label: 'IC Mount Type' %>
    <%= f.input :ic_package, label: 'IC Package' %>
    <%= f.input :ic_quantityOnHand, label: 'Quantity On Hand' %>
    <%= f.input :ic_quantityOnOrder, label: 'Quantity On Order' %>





    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**parts/new_ic.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'ic_form' %>
```

**parts/new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New part</h1>

<%= link_to 'IC', 'new_ic' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', parts_path %>
```

**parts_controller.rb**

```
class PartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_part, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  before_filter :initialize_parts

  def initialize_parts
    @parts = Part.new
  end


  # GET /parts
  # GET /parts.json
  def index
    @parts = Part.all
  end

  # GET /parts/1
  # GET /parts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /parts/new
  def new
    @part = Part.new
  end

  # GET /parts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /parts
  # POST /parts.json
  def create
    @part = Part.new(part_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @part.save
        format.html { redirect_to @part, notice: 'Part was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @part }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @part.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /parts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /parts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @part.update(part_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @part, notice: 'Part was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @part.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /parts/1
  # DELETE /parts/1.json
  def destroy
    @part.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to parts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_part
      @part = Part.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def part_params
      params[:part]
    end
end
```

**routes.rb** Pretty sure i screwed this one up too

```
Pms::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :parts

  resources :parts
  root to: "parts#new_ic"

end
```

**rake routes Output:**

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    parts GET    /parts(.:format)          parts#index
          POST   /parts(.:format)          parts#create
 new_part GET    /parts/new(.:format)      parts#new
edit_part GET    /parts/:id/edit(.:format) parts#edit
     part GET    /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#show
          PATCH  /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#update
          PUT    /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#update
          DELETE /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#destroy
          GET    /parts(.:format)          parts#index
          POST   /parts(.:format)          parts#create
          GET    /parts/new(.:format)      parts#new
          GET    /parts/:id/edit(.:format) parts#edit
          GET    /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#show
          PATCH  /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#update
          PUT    /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#update
          DELETE /parts/:id(.:format)      parts#destroy
     root GET    /                         parts#new_ic
```

Comment: can you put the output of rake routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is in this line:

```
<%= link_to 'IC', 'new_ic' %>
```

[`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) should look like this:

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile) 
#Profile is the name 
#profile_path(@profile) is the link
```

Try this instead:

```
#parts/new.html.erb
<%= link_to 'IC', root_path %>
```

in your routes,  `root GET    /                         parts#new_ic` is linking to your `new_ic` action.  I'd disagree with the way you access it (via root) - but it will work if you want to access the `new_ic` action.  Why is this your root route, though?

Comment: what would new_ic_path be?

Comment: if you look at the output of `rake routes`, `new_ic` should be the path designated for `paths#new` - and you write the link to this path by using `new_ic_path` - actually just saw your update, will change answer

Comment: the problem with that is that i will have several different forms for different types of components (like resistors and capacitors, etc.), so i want the parts/new page to contain links to the different forms (such as new_ic)

Comment: well that's something you have to figure out in your routing file.  give this a read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: ok, for now I'm gonna try and get the form to work as it is. I am still not clear about what "new_part_path" should be.